# How to run a python definition inside a .py file from the shell?

Tags: command-line, python

My function sits inside a .py file with the very same name as the function:

```
emp@emp:~$ python ~/Dropbox/emp/Python/stromkosten_pro_jahr.pyempedokles@empedokles:~$ stromkosten_pro_jahr(20,3)
bash: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort »20,3«
emp@emp:~$
```

Where's the error?

Comment: It could be me, but I am not getting it clear, what is the function, what is the file and how are you calling the function?

Comment: empedokles@empedokles:~$ python ~/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten_pro_jahr.py
empedokles@empedokles:~$ stromkosten_pro_jahr(20,3)

//The function has the same name as the py-file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You can then ping the user who asked for the information by leaving a comment and including a `@` before their username. For example, to ping me: `@terdon`. Also, please translate the error so we can understand what bash is complaining about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `cd` into the directory where your python file is located and then invoke the python interactive shell to be able to call and run functions interactively.

```
# cd to the directory
$ cd ~/Dropbox/emp/Python/

# invoke the python interactive shell
$ python     # use `python3` to invoke the Python3 shell
```

The Python interactive shell would look something like:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Here you may import the module (your *.py file) and 
run the functions written therein:

```
>>> from stromkosten_pro_jahr import stromkosten_pro_jahr
>>> stromkosten_pro_jahr(20,3)
[The output of function would be shown right here]
```

For more information, I would suggest to go through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there an easier way, like the F5-run in IDLE?

Comment: @user272441 There sure is. I would suggest you to take a look at different text editors and IDEs like Sublime Text, Geany, Pycharm Community Edition, Komodo Edit etc. You would be able to run the files in a much easier way. Moreover, you would learn the different options as you keep learning Python. Keep at it and good luck :)

Comment: @user272441 Once you develop a bit more understanding of Python, you may use the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to develop your program which would accept command-line options.

Comment: Do you happen to know what is needed in sublime text (I actually use it)?

Comment: @user272441 Put the code you want to run inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` (this is optional but recommended). Then build your program from *Tools* menu, *Build*. Tinker with *Build System* if it doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: While I pressed build it doesn't seem to allow me to use my function?

Comment: @user272441 I don't quite understand your last message. But I would suggest to search for whatever problems you are having and I'm sure you would find the answer pretty quickly yourself. If that doesn't work, ask a new question properly explaining what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

As I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line?answertab=votes#tab-top), you can run `python`'s function directly from `bash` like:

```
$ python -c 'from a import stromkosten_pro_jahr; stromkosten_pro_jahr(20,3)'
```

Where `a` is your file/module's name (`a.py`).

**But the important thing is to be in the same directory as your file is.**

Answer (score 1):

You can not call Python functions directly from the Bash shell. You are getting this particular error because bash is parsing your arguments *(20,3)* like so:

```
$ echo (20,3)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `20,3'
```

To pass the brackets as a string you need to escape them:

```
$ echo \(20,3\) '(1,2)'
(20,3) (1,2)
```

But this still will not magically run as Python code - you will need to parse the command line arguments in your Python program (save as x.py):

```
import sys

def fn(a,b):
  print a+b

eval(sys.argv[1])
```

Then:

```
$ python x.py 'fn(0,13)'
13
```

Comment: There would be more explanation needed for your code which starts with import sys. Thanks.